# Why is NA Returned when you run slicing without parenthensis?

Tags: r

Consider this vector:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

When we do a normal slice,

```
x <- x[2:4]
```

It returns:

```
"B" "C" "D"
```

Why is it that when we perform this line of code, NA is returned?

```
x[1+1:4]
"B" "C" "D" NA
```

However when we put a parenthesis around the plus sign,

```
x[(1+1):4]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

It returns the correct output.

Comment: check the output of `1+1:4` and `(1+1):4`

Comment: Here, the `:` operator **by convention** signifies a stronger bond than `+`. Therefore, the first vector could also have been written as `1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+4` because `1+...` applies to all elements of the vector. Compare this to addition/ subtraction vs. multiplication/ division in mathematics.

Comment: Read about [Operator Syntax and Precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are slicing with two different set of indexes.

In the first case `1+1:4` you are producing a vector that goes from 1 to 4, `1:4` and then 1 is added, hence `2,3,4,5`. In your vector the 5th position does not exist so you get an `NA`.

In the second vector you are slicing taking the positions `(1+1):4` which corresponds to `2,3,4`. This are all elements that exist in your initial vector and so you have the corresponding values